# Make Shakapacker ES6 functions available in inline Rails views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, typescript, webpack, webpacker, shakapacker

Rails version: 6.1.3

I am upgrading from Webpacker 5.2 to Shakapacker 7.2.2, and my ES6 functions defined globally on the `window` object are not available in inline script tags on an ERB view. My project uses both Sprockets and Webpacker/Shakapacker. Here's an example:

**In app/javascript/lib/device_detect.ts:**

```
import { isMobile } from "react-device-detect";

export function isMobileBrowser() {
  return isMobile;
}
```

**In app/javascript/packs/application.ts:**

```
import { isMobileBrowser } from '../lib/device_detect';

(window as any).isMobileBrowser = isMobileBrowser;
```

**In app/views/users/dashboard.html.erb:**

```
<div class="dashboard">
  ...

</div>

<script>
  if (isMobileBrowser()) {
    ...
  }
</script>
```

With my previous Webpacker setup on both development and production, this works just fine. But with Shakapacker, I receive this error in the browser console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: isMobileBrowser is not defined
```

One of my theories is that Webpacker was not chunking any of my assets and so it was all compiled into one file before being delivered, so I disabled asset chunking. However, that didn't work.

My app has a lot of inline scripts, so I'd prefer not to rewrite/convert them all in some way. I am hoping I can make everything work just as before with Shakapacker instead.

I've tried a lot of things, and nothing has worked. I'd appreciate any help!